# ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I have my application running on an `ec2` instance.

I can successfully `ssh` into my application but when I `cd` in to the correct folder and run `ls` I get the following error:

`ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied`

It seems like it has something to do with my user permissions because running the application also throws a `403 Forbidden` error.

The permissions for my application folder are as follows:

`d-wx-wx--x  17 ubuntu ubuntu    4096 Apr 20 10:53 application-name`

Do I need to change this to something else to make it work? And how?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This error makes sense if you don't have enough privileges to read that directory. try changing the permissions for current user or change the access mode to global i.e 777
For example:

```
sudo bash
chmod 775 .
```

Comment: You should almost never give '777' rights on any UNIX file. That's a bad security advise. '775' is way much acceptable.

Answer (score 23):

This is basically caused when the current user doesn't have enough permission to read/write/execute the contents of that directory.

**Here's how you can fix it**:

To grant the user permission to just the current directory, you could do this:

```
sudo chmod 775 directory_name
```

OR

```
sudo chmod a+rwx,o-w directory_name
```

To grant the user permission to the current directory, it's subdirectories and files, you could do this:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 directory_name
```

OR

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx,o-w directory_name
```

**Note**:

- `chmod` means **change mode** or in a more literal sense **change access permissions**.
- `-R` means change files and directories recursively.
- `a` means all users
- `r` means read permission
- `w` means write permission
- `x` means execute permission
- `o` means others
- `+` means add
- `-` means remove.

So it means recursively add read, write and execute permissions to everyone, but then remove write permissions from others.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 7):

You don't have read permission on your folder.

Run `chmod 775 application-name` to allow read in your folder.

You'll find additional info about chmod at this link: https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb

Comment: I like this answer the best of all of these because `read` is the permission that matters for ls.  `chmod 775` is still too general of an answer, but yes it will probably solve your problem (`444` will also solve this problem).  If possible, look at the individual case and choose the correct permissions for the situation.